# How can i delete a row that contains an error cell

Tags: excel, vba

Im not too familier with vba, but i want to make a macro that deletes any row that has an error inside one of its cells.
I recorded this macro below and if gives me the error: "Run-time error '1004': Delete method of range class failed"

```
    Sub Macro9()
'
' Macro9 Macro
'

'
    Rows("5:100").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

I would greatly apprecite your help if you know how to fix this.
Thank you.

Comment: The result means that there are no errors found.

Comment: @ScottCraner - wouldn't the `Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas, 16).Select` fail if that were the case? Would throw a "No cells were found" error, I think.

Comment: @BigBen yes, it would.  The only other thing I can think of is that there is overlapping ranges, but that would be: `1004: Cannot use that command on overlapping selections`

Comment: Yeah, we need more detail of the setup.

Comment: I'm sorry, please excuse my ignorance but what is an overlapping range? Also i should note that when i click debug the error seems to be coming from the "Selection.EntireRow.Delete" part because it is highlighted in yellow. I hope this helps.

Comment: What is the setup of your sheet? Can you share a sample screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Hei, you need to order your cell, so all the errors will be together. Afther that you can use your macro

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).